# angular $(event.target).addclass not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, events, dom-events

I am working on angularjs. I have a button on html page, on ng-click event it will call a function in controller passing the parameter 'event'.

```
< button ng-click="addStatus($event)"> ADD < /button>
```

Now in a controller, for `addStatus` function I am passing `$event` parameter. In `addStatus` function, for `event.target` I am adding a class named 'added-status'.

```
$scope.addStatus = function ($event){
    
    $(event.target).addClass('added-status'); 
}
```

Everything works fine on Chrome but for Firefox its giving an error 'Event is not defined'. What can be done to work this well in Mozilla Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

if(!event)
{event= window.event;}

Include this code in the controller with above solution, it will define the event for Firefox as it was not there.

So, the final code will be

```
if(!event){
  event= window.event;
}
$scope.addStatus = function ($event){
    $(event.target).addClass('added-status'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you passed two parameters in the ng-click in html part But in the controller `$scope.addStatus` function you passed only one parameter that is second argument in the first. obviously it is undefined .

Do the change

In html

```
<button ng-click="addStatus($event)"> ADD < /button>
```

In controller

```
$scope.addStatus = function (event){
    $(event.target).addClass('added-status'); 
}
```

Comment: I removed the first argument and even $ sign for event in controller, but still its not working! Firefox giving same error : 'Event is not defined'.